# How to access wampserver remotely

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to develop an Java Application under Netbeans IDE and I'm using Wampserver as server software. So I try to create an JDBC to access my data base remotely (under my lan) but noting happen even by changing the configuration file in wampserver according to what i found on the internet. if any one have an idea how we do that please help.

Comment: If you know how to use `nmap` (command line), you can start testing if your MySQL server is open for connections. You can just type in the command line `nmap -p 3306 192.168.33.06`. Just replace 192.168.33.06 with the your mysql server's IP address. Your MySQL server is maybe online but only accessible within localhost and can't be accessed by other computers on the network. Check also if there is a firewall that blocks port 3306 of your MySQL server.

Comment: another thing to note is that in MySQL's config file `my.cnf` you may need to  set the bind address to 0.0.0.0 like so: `bind-address=0.0.0.0`
and the account you need to use in connecting should be like `khelfa@%` and not `khelfa@localhost`. In phpMyAdmin, you can create a user there and assign `%` as the host of the new user so he/she could access the server even from a different machine

Comment: Thanks abel, it is realy helpfull.....tks a lot.